# Modify existing .htaccess so that it ignores subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file in place, and whilst I know it is nowhere near optimal (and probably a bit cringeworthy) - it just works.

```
# Prevents public viewing of .htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Custom 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.domain.com/404/

# Turn on rewriting and set rewriting base
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([a-z]{2,4})$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Force WWW and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove .php extension
RewriteRule ^(properties)/(all|location1|location2|location3)/(all|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)/(asc|desc) $1.php?location=$2&bedrooms=$3&sort-by=$4
RewriteRule ^(properties)/(all|location1|location2|location3)/(all|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9) $1.php?location=$2&bedrooms=$3
RewriteRule ^(properties)/(all|location1|location2|location3) $1.php?location=$2
RewriteRule ^(view-property)/(.*)/(print-view) $1.php?id=$2&print=true
RewriteRule ^(view-property)/(.*)/ $1.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Our new website is now ready to be pushed to our newly created staging environment for testing. In this instance it would be `staging.domain.com` but we're having problems actually accessing this staging URL.

EDIT - Just to clarify, the problem is that accessing `staging.domain.com` redirects to `https://www.domain.com`.

We believe the problem is caused by the rewrite rules we have in place above. I have researched a few possible solutions include adding additional conditions to the existing rewrite rules such as:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^staging\.domain\.com`

or adding a new condition/rule such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]
```

but unfortunately none of these have worked. Working with `.htaccess` files is really not my strong suit, so if anyone could offer any assistance that would be great.

P.S. The new site is powered by Laravel 5.3 so I will be getting rid of the terrible attempt at rewriting rules (those at the bottom) when we go live!

Comment: Point your staging domain to a different document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top rules must be changed to this to remove hardcoded domain name in target URL:

```
# Turn on rewriting and set rewriting base
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force WWW and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# Remove .php extension and rest of the rewrite rules
```

Comment: I have changed the rules as detailed above and whilst the live site continues to work as expected, the staging URL `staging.domain.com` continues to redirect straight to `https://www.domain.com`.

Comment: Using `curl` returns the following: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"><html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><h1>Moved Permanently</h1><p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.domain.com/">here</a>.</p></body></html>`

Comment: Do you still have any redirect rule in your .htaccess? My answer has no rule that redirects to `https://www.tynesidelettings.com/`

Comment: No, the only rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file now is as you answered above. Could this perhaps be something on our server that is making the redirect occur?

Comment: Yes there can be something outside this .htaccess. Can you rename .htaccess to `.htaccess.bak` and retest from `curl`?

Comment: Yes, having renamed my `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.bak` and using `curl` I am getting the same response. I'll get in touch with my hosting provider to see what's going wrong on the server side. Thank you for your help!